# NSDictionary objectForKey not working

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSDictionary that when I NSLog prints this out

```
{
    206510 = 1;
    622845 = 1;
    926131 = "";
    100000977163362 = "";
}
```

Why does

```
[dict objectForKey:@"206510"]
```

gives null?

This is how I setup the dictionary in the first place.

```
[dict setObject:[status objectForKey:@"game_status"] forKey:(NSString*) [status objectForKey:@"id"]];
```

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: Presumably that `[status objectForKey:@"id"]` isn't actually returning a string; what type is it?

Answer (score 1):

Are your keys strings or numbers?  NSDictionary keys off an `id` (your cast to NSString is unnecessary, and possibly wrong), eg. any objective-c object, you may want (entirely guesswork here):

```
[NSNumber numberWithDouble: 206510.0]
```